# Resizing elements dynamically using javascript and the element.style attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, resize, window-resize

I have tried searching for this but can't find any answers.

*Details:* I am trying to build a javascript carousel without using any libraries. My implementation is probably not the best. What I have decided to do is have a long div.carousel-track that contains many .carousel-items (these items are created from an object in javascript). The .carousel-track is wider than the page and has overflow: hidden on, so I can choose to have one item on the page at a time.

Because I am using bootstrap for the project in which it sits, I need it to align with bootstraps containers and columns. I do this by:

- Getting the windows inner width, dividing by 12 and storing it.
- When creating the .carousel-items I use this number to set the width and margins.

**The probelm:** This works initally, but when I try to resize the page and have the items resize too it will not, and instead stays with the old value. The variable that sets the width changes on resize, so why are the elements not when I re render them?

```
            // Set global variables for the window.
        var w = document.defaultView,
            d = document,
            e = document.documentElement,
            g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
            y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;

        // Set the initial size of the bootstrap grid column for dynamic elements.
        var colOne = x / 12;

        window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", function () {
            console.log('optimizedResize firing');
            w = document.defaultView,
                d = document,
                e = document.documentElement,
                g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
                x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
                y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
            // Reset the size of bootsrap columns depending on the screen.
            colOne = x / 12;
            console.log(`x: ${x}, col-one: ${colOne}`);
            view.infinite.resize();
        });


        var view = {
            infinite: {
                init: function () {
                    console.log(controller.getCurrentItem());
                    this.rightItem = controller.getRightItem();
                    this.centerItem = controller.getCurrentItem();
                    this.leftItem = controller.getLeftItem();

                    this.HTMLparentElement = document.createElement('div');
                    this.HTMLcarouselTrackElement = document.getElementById('carousel-track');

                    // Offset the carousel by 12 bootstrap columns (aka a whole page).
                    this.HTMLcarouselTrackElement.style.transform = "translateX(-" + colOne * 12 + "px)";

                    view.infinite.render();
                },
                render: function () {
                    console.log('rendering');
                    var carouselItems = [this.leftItem, this.centerItem, this.rightItem];

                    // Appends all the items in the carousel list in a row.
                    for (var i = 0; i < carouselItems.length; i++) {

                        this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer = document.createElement('div');
                        // Add classes for styling the carousel container.
                        this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer.classList.add('inner-carousel', 'carousel-item');
                        view.infinite.resize();
                        this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer.appendChild(HTMLprojectGradientOverlay);
                        // Append the whole carousel item to the carousel track.
                        this.HTMLparentElement.appendChild(this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer);
                    }

                    this.HTMLcarouselTrackElement.innerHTML = this.HTMLparentElement.innerHTML;

                },
                resize: function () {
                    // Dynamically set the width + margins to match the bootstrap width.
                    console.log(colOne);
                    this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer.style.width = (colOne * 10) + "px";
                    this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer.style.marginLeft = (colOne) + "px";
                    this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer.style.marginRight = (colOne) + "px";
                    console.log(this.HTMLcarouselItemContainer);
                }
            },

            move: {
                init: function () {
                    console.log('init move');
                    this.rbtn = d.createElement('button');
                    this.lbtn = d.createElement('button');
                    this.HTMLlistCellRight = document.createElement('li');
                    this.HTMLlistCellLeft = document.createElement('li');
                    this.HTMLspanIndicatorElemRight = document.createElement('span');
                    this.HTMLspanIndicatorElemLeft = document.createElement('span');
                    this.rbtn.innerText = "right";
                    this.lbtn.innerText = "left";

                    var HTMLindicatorListElem = document.getElementById('indicator-list');

                    this.HTMLspanIndicatorElemLeft.appendChild(this.lbtn);
                    this.HTMLlistCellLeft.appendChild(this.HTMLspanIndicatorElemLeft);

                    this.HTMLspanIndicatorElemRight.appendChild(this.rbtn);
                    this.HTMLlistCellRight.appendChild(this.HTMLspanIndicatorElemRight);

                    HTMLindicatorListElem.appendChild(this.HTMLlistCellLeft);
                    HTMLindicatorListElem.appendChild(this.HTMLlistCellRight);



                    this.rbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        return function () {
                            controller.rightRotation();
                            view.infinite.init();
                        };

                    }());

                    this.lbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        return function () {
                            controller.leftRotation();
                            view.infinite.init();
                        };

                    }());

                    view.move.render();
                },
                render: function () {

                }
            },
        };
```

Comment: That's huge amount of code, you should post only what's necessary to reproduce the problem. You're probably looking for resize event, just calculate the width again on resize: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Comment: Or if you post so much code, please provide a snippet with the rest of the related code, or use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share it with us

Comment: Sorry for posting so much, I removed as much as I could as I am not sure where the problem is originating.

Comment: I am calculating the width again on resize, and it should be working as the variable that sets the width is changing correctly, however the element remains the same size.